# Spring Batch giving All bytes to be written were not successfully written error

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have written a spring batch job that uses a flatFileItemWriter to write a huge amount of data to the file.  The job is intermittently failing with the following error `org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.FlushFailedException: Could not write to output buffer`.
I looked into the source code and found that it is specifically failing at 
[this place](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/support/transaction/TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.java#L124), which implies that the bytesWritten is not equal to the bytes it read. Does anyone here know why is it failing at this step. Thanks.

Here's the complete stack trace of the error:

```
Encountered an error executing step step in job exportDataJob; org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.FlushFailedException: Could not write to output buffer 
   at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareBufferedWriter$1.beforeCommit(TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.java:111)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:932)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
   at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:150) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81) 
   at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374) 
   at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) 
   at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:257) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:392) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135) 
   at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) 
   at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128) 
   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.execute(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:214) 
   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:231) 
   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:123) 
   at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.run(JobLauncherCommandLineRunner.java:117) 
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) 
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) 
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) 
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) 
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) 
   at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) 
   at com.intuit.sbg.integrations.batch.Application.main(Application.java:48) 
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) 
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) 
   at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:587) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
   at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperJarApp.run(WrapperJarApp.java:394) 
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: All bytes to be written were not successfully written 
   at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareBufferedWriter$1.complete(TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.java:124) 
   at org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.TransactionAwareBufferedWriter$1.beforeCommit(TransactionAwareBufferedWriter.java:107) 
   ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Comment: This usually happens when it is not possible to write bytes to the file due to a full disk. Are you sure there is enough space to write data to the output file?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thank you! The issue was indeed not having enough disk space to write data to the output file.

Comment: Or might be possible if file itself got moved and no longer available to write to the directory.I had similar issue when one of the cronJob tried to move file to s3 bucket from the location even if file writing was not completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the disk is complete, and all the data cannot be written.

Making enough space for the data on the disk would solve the problem.